# Drop Down value in selenium using java

Tags: selenium, dropdown

Could you please help me in selecting drop down value in selenium using java code.
My issue is that in HTML code, i do not have SELECT class.

This is the code i have tried :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.id("Some Value"));

    for (WebElement element: elements){
        new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.Arrow_Down).perform();
                if(Element.getText().equals("Cliam Document")){
                    element.click();
                }
    }
```

Below is html snippet :

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSele‌​‌​ctor" value="" aria-invalid="true" type="text">
<span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField">Enter or select an entry template</span>
<input name="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSe‌​‌​lector" value="" type="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Here is the HTML part from inspecting element:

<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSele‌​ctor" value="" aria-invalid="true" type="text"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField">Enter or select an entry template</span><input name="ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSe‌​lector" value="" type="hidden"></div>

Comment: Update the html snippet in question itself and describe  in details

Comment: Not able to add HTML part in question.

Comment: The Drop-down is of Hidden type. So u have to first click on the drop down, then the Hidden drop down code will appear in html. Where u can use method selectbytext(). I guess it may work

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code (Here I'm assuming that dropdown options appear after clicking the dropdown field):

```
   WebElement yourDropdown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSele‌​‌​ctor"));
   yourDropdown .click();
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ecm_widget_AddContentItemGeneralPane_0_entryTemplateSele‌​‌​ctor input"));

for (WebElement element: elements){

            if(Element.getText().equals("Cliam Document")){
                element.click();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps:

Step 1: Enter value in the input field.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("Enter xpath here")).sendkeys("enter text here");

Step 2: Now to select value from the list

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Some Value"));

    for (WebElement element: elements){
          String element_text = element.gettext();
                if(element_text.equals("Cliam Document")){
                    element.click();
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below steps, will be able to select value from dropDown

Step 1. 
    WebElement dropdownTab = driver.findElements(By.xpath("dropdown locator")).click(); //Click on the dropdown tab

Step2:
    List options = driver.findElements(By.tag_name('option')); //Get all the options

Step 3:

```
for (WebElement element: options){
            if(options.getText().equals("Text Name which needs to be selected")){
                element.click();
                break;
            }
}
```

This should work, if still you are facing issue - Please provide the url where you are trying...will post the exact code